# retrieving the user facebook information on my android application

Tags: android, facebook

I've integrated facebook in my android application using `facebook sdk` and succeded to do a login from my app.Next I wanna retrieve on my android application all this user's personal information(Info).But I haven't found any tutorials on that, yet.Can someone give me a hint of how I should proceed?Thank you:)

EDIT:
As I understand from there this is the way how the requests for friends/user information should be done.
But there is something I don't understand....Is this method called automaticaly after I logg in?????

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
 String accessToken = facebook.getAccessToken();
try
{
        params.putString("format", "json");
        params.putString("access_token", accessToken);

        String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+Id;

        ......
}
```

This is the way I logg in:

```
    tweet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            postMessage();

        }
    });
```

I have a `button`  `tweet` and a listener that calls for my method that looks like this:

```
public void postMessage() {

    if (facebookConnector.getFacebook().isSessionValid()) {
        postMessageInThread();
    } else {
        SessionEvents.AuthListener listener = new SessionEvents.AuthListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthSucceed() {
                postMessageInThread();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthFail(String error) {

            }
        };
        SessionEvents.addAuthListener(listener);
        facebookConnector.login();
    }
}
```

Question:First I definitly have to logg in and after that to retrieve the information/friends list and so on.....but where should I call for this methods??This is extremly unclear to me....are they called automaticaly after I logg in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the Graph API on Facebook, it'll return JSON to you with the infos you need
Read the paragraph called "Calling the graph API" here : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android and follow the links

Comment: What method do you speak about ? There are 2 examples in the Facebook Android SDK where you can find the way to do it : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples :)